# How to fix my input overlapping my entered text?

Tags: html, css

My input overlapping text on top, for 1 or 2 pixels.
Using SCSS with React.JS

[image: My input here]

```css
.find-input {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #262B36;
  padding: 13px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.find-input:focus {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <input class="find-input" />
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide the parent CSS, the current CSS seems to generate no error for me as your output, it may be because of some external CSS. According to current CSS the output is: https://i.ibb.co/yp2rGZr/input.png

Comment: NisooJadhav, ok i provide.

Comment: The code you have provided does not yield the same results from your screenshot.

Comment: ksav, yes it is but on my server it's same as i provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try increasing height or reducing top/bottom padding.

Seeing your HTML would help...

Comment: this is what i get https://imgur.com/vP8DaQs

Comment: is there any other code connected to the input?